# FireBird install using InstallShield

Tags: firebird, installshield, installscript

I can't seem to find a good script or anything to use for installing Firebird (the InterBase-decendent RDBMS) using InstallShield. There is a way to silently install it using the firebird install executable, but I don't know enough about InstallShieldscripts to be able to do it! If anyone knows any information on 
a) how to execute an exe from InstallShield
b) how to install firebord using InstallShield
I would be very appreciative! Thanks a lot, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably reword your question to get answers about how to execute an external program using command line parameters in an InstallShield script. Maybe the documentation would have enough info on that already.

Regarding the installation of Firebird, please have a look at [this document](http://firebird.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/firebird/firebird2/builds/install/arch-specific/win32/installation_scripted.txt?view=markup) which comes with the Firebird installation and shows all available switches for the Firebird setup executable. If you don't want the user to see that your program is installing Firebird you should probably use the */SP-*, the */VERYSILENT* and */SUPPRESSMSGBOXES* switches. Other switches worth looking into are */NOICONS* to suppress the creation of a program group in the start menu, and */COMPONENTS=...* to install only what is absolutely necessary for your program to function.

Please note that installing Firebird is only a part of what you should do. For clear separation from other programs using Firebird you should create a new Firebird user account with password, and it's always a good idea to add an alias for your database to the *aliases.conf* file.